# Additional div container breaks html5 video play function

Tags: javascript, html5-video, slick.js

I just created a example for a slick carousel with html5 videos: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PLvreP

In the first slide the video start automatically. In the second slide there is an additional div container wrapping the video-tag and there the autoplay is not working anymore.

What should I do to make it work even if there is an additional container inside?

Thank you for your support!
L

This is the example of the second html markup which doesn't work:

```
<div class="item video">
    <div>
      <video class="slide-video slide-media" loop muted preload="metadata" poster="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B_koKn2rKOkLSXZCakVGZWhOV00">
        <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/138504815.sd.mp4?s=8a71ff38f08ec81efe50d35915afd426765a7526&profile_id=112" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
      <p class="caption">HTML 5 Video</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, no its is not. It is linked to this video: 
https://player.vimeo.com/external/138504815.sd.mp4?s=8a71ff38f08ec81efe50d35915afd426765a7526&profile_id=112

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding an extra div, you are breaking the code that selects the video to be played. In your `playPauseVideo` function :

```
video = currentSlide.children("video").get(0);
```

Now, there is no more children with the "video" tag, as your video is now a grandchild of the `currentSlide` div.

Adapt the way you're selecting that video element and that should fix it

```
video = currentSlide.children("div").children("video").get(0);
```

or

```
video = currentSlide.find("video").get(0);
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OqeJxV)

**EDIT regarding your last comment :**

> Unfortunately there is no effect on my website and no errors shown.
>   How can I find out where the error could be? Is there a method to send
>   logs to the console? I already searching for many hours

The thing is, you're selecting your video and before calling play/pause, you're testing if it's null :

```
video = currentSlide.children("video").get(0);
if (video != null) {
  if (control === "play"){
    video.play();
  } else {
    video.pause();
  }
}
```

So, if you want to log an error, you could add an `else` block and use `console.error()`

```
if (video != null) {
  if (control === "play"){
    video.play();
  } else {
    video.pause();
  }
} else {
   console.error("The video was not found");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just see that this is working currently with codepen. Unfortunately there is no effect on my website and no errors shown. How can I find out where the error could be? Is there a method to send logs to the console? I already searching for many hours.

Comment: @Luke I answered your questions in my edit. Check it out.

Comment: Thank you very much. The video ist there. When I make a right click i can press play and it plays. The play function is somehow not triggered. Can I check if the video element is not found by the selector?

Comment: I just found out where the problem was. This selector only works if the class is in second place. If there are more than one class infront it got not selected.

slideType = currentSlide.attr("class").split(" ")[1];